# JMeter - Limitation in HTTPRequest parameter

Tags: httprequest, limit, jmeter

I'm using JMETER 2.4

I'm using HTTP request sampler with a Post action.
In this sampler, I have a parameter. The value for this parameter that I have to sent, is more than 5375 characters.

When I run this case in JMeter, the value seems to be sent from my end, but my website does not see this value.

When I check the check the received value using Fiddler the parameter is showing Empty.
After many try it seems JMeter has a limitation around 5375 characters for the parameter's value in a HTTPRequest sampler.

Do you know how to avoid this limitation?

Comment: I recommend upgrade your JMeter, version 2.4 is too old.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you may have reached the maximum URL lenght (is 8K).
You may try if a more recent version has increased this limit, but probably even a real browser will find the same limitation.

A complete discussion about maximum URL length can be find [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter as of 2.9 has not such limitation, it respects HTTP Standard which puts a limit on a GET request length (as sbos61 pointed it).

But it seems from your question you are using POST (not GET).

Can you show your sampler configuration ?

Anyway I highly suggest upgrading to JMeter 2.9, I have just tested with this 2.9 version , and there is no problem.